# zip multiple folders into a zip file using terminal

Tags: command-line, filesystem, compression, zip

I wish to store a few folders in a zip file and then convert that zip file into a jar.

I have the following folders : `META-INF` and `org`.

I tried the following command:

```
zip META-INF/ org/ wordcount.zip
```

But wordcount.zip was not created.

Comment: Have you considered using the `jar` tool if you aim to create a Java Archive?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The syntax is the other way around; you give the name of the `.zip` file to create first in the list. Also, use the `-r` flag for recursion into directories:

```
zip -r wordcount.zip META-INF org
```

This creates a file `wordcount.zip` (you may be able to omit the `.zip` in the command as this is automatically added if possible) with all the contents of the two directories `META-INF` and `org`